# How to make postfix send email when fail delivery attempt?

Tags: smtp, postfix

i'm setting up postfix as a MX server. Basically it will receive email, do all filterings and route to domain SMTP server. In case of failure when trying to send the email to the destination SMTP, is it possible for postfix to send email to the administrator?

TQVM

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism in Postfix for delivering complete extra copies of bounce
messages. Even the sender will only get headers if the bounce message would otherwise 
be over the bounce_size_limit. You could try using "softbounce=yes" and manually
watch the queue and remove/forward from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
notify_classes = bounce
bounce_notice_recipient = <admin email id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Some issue with the browser.

Try

notify_classes = bounce

bounce_notice_recipient = adminemailid

in "/etc/postfix/main.cf"